# Encode and decode custom executable code

Tags: java, binaryfiles

Let's admit it, we've all once opened an executable file in text editing programs.
This is what you get when opening them using Notepad++:
[The things you see when opening executable files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVkl2.png)

I'm trying to recreate this effect using Java except I need to be able to decode the code.
I tried using String.getBytes but that only gave me numbers.
How would I do this?

Comment: Just what did I say wrong to get a vote-down?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original code of a .jar file by using a decompiler.

JD-Gui is very simple and should do the trick for you: http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: I didn't say I want to decompile jar files.

Comment: What do you want to do then? The thing that gave you numbers is supposed to convert a String into a byte array (numbers).

Comment: I need to encode the String into some executable code (that is decodeable) like in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look for binary encryption or binary encoding. I'm not familiar with how to do it for Java but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I did a Google search but to no avail.